# Haskell: Lazy download with Curl

Tags: haskell, curl, lazy-evaluation

How to use laziness with this [package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/download-curl-0.1.3) or perhaps some other package and how to fix this code, so it won't download the whole file but just some first bytes?

```
import qualified  Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import Network.Curl.Download.Lazy

main = do
  Right body <- openLazyURI "http://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/7.6.3/ghc-7.6.3-x86_64-unknown-linux.tar.bz2"
  return $ B.take 32 body
```

Comment: You can't control how much it downloads, just that the download is lazy.  It'll be downloading in chunks, specific to the implementation and possibly your network connection, but if you're using the lazy variant, it should be returning a lazy bytestring already, according to the documentation.  Is this code not working as expected?

Comment: @bheklilr It downloads the whole file as I said, only then it returns lazy bytestring. I would be happy to control at least chunks to download.

Comment: Looking closer at the documentation, it seems that the difference between the strict and lazy functions in this library are their return type, not their behavior.  The `openLazyURI` function returns a lazy `ByteString`, while `openURI` returns a strict bytestring.  This is likely to provide an interface if you're using lazy `ByteString`s or strict ones.

Comment: So there is no easy way to read chunks lazily from url then?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's impossible with existing libraries, but I don't know of an easy way.

Comment: Are you sure you want to? Leaving the connection open can lead to weird bugs when you exhaust resources

Comment: @jozefg It wasn't my intention to leave any open connections. I just want to have a real lazy bytestring so that I can use it with `Conduit` package as a source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out and even wrote an example [application](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/web-application-with-concurrency) explaining everything.

Comment: The link is broken: Page not found, Error 404.

Answer (score 3):

The following should do the trick:

```
import Network.Curl.Download
import Network.Curl.Opts

...
Right body <- openURIWithOpts [CurlMaxFileSize 32] someUrl
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I need, but I found that some other options include callback functions, that may solve my problem I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using http-conduit:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Data.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB

main = withManager $ \m -> do
    req <- parseUrl "http://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/7.6.3/ghc-7.6.3-x86_64-unknown-linux.tar.bz2"
    res <- http req m
    responseBody res $$+- CB.take 32
```

The advantage here is that there's no lazy I/O involved: all resource management is completely deterministic.

Comment: Thanks, the only disadvantage is that it only works with http.

Comment: You mean as opposed to https, or as opposed to ftp? If the former, http-conduit does have full SSL support, so you should be good to go.